# 'ORDER BY' total for location on an SSRS graph in VisualStudio2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, group-by

In visual-Studio 2010, I am trying to create an SSRS graph to display sales in order of totalsold.
The graph came out with the right information, but not the right order.

This is the code I inserted into "DataSets"

```
SELECT          SUM(TotalSold) Total, st.Name Territory
FROM            SalesOrder so
LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesTerritory st
ON              so.TerritoryID=st.TerritoryID
GROUP BY        [Name]
ORDER BY        Total desc
```

The end result should look like the first graph (A-01). The current
graph looks like the second graph (B-01)
Do I need to change the code?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open 'Category Group Properties' window, then change the sorting order by total to "Z to A" as depicted in the screenshot. Select 'OK' and go to 'Preview' to ascertain that it worked.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to series group properties and change the sorting by total "Z to A" see screen shot for your reference ...

[image]

Comment: With either Total or territory entered, I went into the  sorting window as you showed, but the graph simply showed each bar with a different color. It did not sort it in order of highest to lowest

Comment: Thanks Naveen Kumar. It did not work inSseries Group Properties, so I tried it in Category Group Properties window, and it worked.

Comment: yes.. i was just posting with same by setting the fill color in series property..